# name not defined, but exists as def

Tags: python-3.x

I've just started working with Python and I have been following a OCR GCSE Computing book.
The code in the book I am supposed to copy is this:

```
#valid_response="True"
while True:
answer=(input("Press A, R, F or Q: "))
if answer in("A", "a"):
  write_file()
elif answer in ("R", "r"):
  read_file()
elif answer in ("F", "f"):
  find_rec()
elif answer in ("Q", "q"):
  break
else:
  print("Invalid Response")

#function to write music details to file

def  write_file():
  """Write details to the file"""

#create a new file or add to an existing file
  f = open("music2.txt","a")
  print ("Enter Details")

  ok=True

  while ok==True:
    serial = (input("Enter Serial "))
    f.write(serial+"\n")
    genre = (input("Enter Genre "))
    f.write(genre+"\n")
    artist = (input("Enter Artist "))
    f.write(artist+"\n")
    title = (input("Enter Title "))
    f.write(title+"\n")
    ask=(input("Another? "))
    if ask in ('y', 'ye', 'yes', 'Y'):
      ok=True
    else:
      ok=False

    f.close()
```

All I get when I run it is that the error "name write_file is not defined".

As far as I can make out, i have defined it in the code. Im using 3.3.4 and wondered if I have missed anything obvious.

Thank you

Comment: Your book is horrible. So much wrong with this code, I don't even know where I should start...

Answer (score 1):

Move the function above the function call. Your main script should always be on the bottom.